# How to use debugging in Github Actions

Tags: terraform

my Terraform plan is failing with error but I would like to be able to debug what the root cause is. I export TF_LOG in my plan but its not working.please how can i use export debugging to see more logs of why Terraform plan is failing? below is a snippet of my Github Actions workflow

```
 - name: Terragrunt Plan
        id: plan
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: | 
          export TF_LOG=DEBUG
          terragrunt run-all plan -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive >/dev/null -out=tfplan
          terragrunt show tfplan
```

Comment: Do you see the error in the output without setting the log level to debug? It should be pretty expressive.

Comment: no,i do not @Marko

Comment: Then how do you know there is an error at all?

Comment: the plan failed with exit code 1  but everything worked successfully on my local machine

Comment: And there are no errors anywhere in the GitHub actions output?

Comment: the output is not saying why plan failed and other passed

Comment: You are redirecting to `/dev/null` so remove that and rerun so there may be something in the logs. Otherwise there is absolutely no way to know what is going on.