# How to use terraform debugging in a github action workflow?

Tags: terraform

When my terraform code failed locally, I am able to see a detailed error message as to why it failed and with that information able to fix it. However, when the same terraform code failed while using GitHub Action workflow, it doesn't give detailed reason why it failed, except "error exit code 1". How can I use terraform debugging on the workflow level to produce detail log only when a step failed. I don't want to configure debugging at the repository level.

```
name: Testing push to branches
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - main

env:
  TERRAFORM_VERSION: "latest"
  TERRAGRUNT_VERSION: "latest"
  TERRAFORM_WORKING_DIR: './test'


jobs:
  plan:
    name: "Terragrunt Plan"
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_WORKING_DIR }}
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1.3.2
        with:
          terraform_version: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_VERSION }}
          terraform_wrapper: true

      - name: Setup Terragrunt
        uses: autero1/action-terragrunt@v1.1.0
        with:
          terragrunt_version: ${{ env.TERRAGRUNT_VERSION }}

      - name: configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1.6.1
        with:
          aws-region: us-east-1
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

      - name: Terragrunt Init
        id: init
        run: terragrunt run-all init -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive

      - name: Terragrunt Validate
        id: validate
        run: terragrunt run-all validate -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive

      - name: Terragrunt Plan
        id: plan
        run: terragrunt run-all plan -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive
```

Comment: Well, there is the `terragrunt-debug` option, not sure if that is what you are asking. Or you could add `2&>1` to the end of the command you want to debug.

Comment: can I use this option at the workflow level which will apply to all steps in my workflow

Comment: and also please how will i add the 2&>1 if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use debugging in Github Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639185/how-to-use-debugging-in-github-actions)